# XAMPP BETA 13: Slow mysql connect

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, xampp

I just installed a fresh xampp beta 13 installation however I noticed in my zend application profiler that connect to mysql database is so slow. I have refreshed many times but same slow result.

```
1020.84ms   connect
0.39ms  SELECT `tipo_usuario`.* FROM `tipo_usuario`
0.40ms  SELECT `palestra`.* FROM `palestra` ORDER BY `hora_inicio_prevista` asc
```

One friend has tested same application on other machine and It is normal, connect in less than 50 ms. I am using pdo mysql dll driver version 5.4.4.0, Client API version mysqlnd 5.0.10 - 20111026.

My environment: Apache/2.4.2 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.4

Any idea why connecting is slow?

Comment: and your connection string is? using tcp? sockets?

Comment: Check xampp/mysql/data/mysql_error.log and post what's in there if you can, chances are the answer is there.

Comment: @MarcB I am using Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo, If I didn't read wrong, It's mysql://

Comment: @Mahn It's here http://pastebin.com/v4fqXfZe

Comment: Can't see anything wrong, did you change anything in the configuration? anything in my.ini? Otherwise I'd suggest to wipe it completely and do a new install.

Comment: @Mahn I didn't change, It's my third install. I noticed mysqli driver works normally maybe it's something with built-in pdo mysql driver.

Comment: Definitively not normal, can you show the code you use to connect to the database with PDO?

Comment: @Mahn I am using zendframework, Here is the code which connects to database http://pastebin.com/FrTthbmn

Comment: @Mahn Look I coded a simple code which connects to database and query a default xampp table http://pastebin.com/r0LX9j1a,

Comment: Try replacing localhost with 127.0.0.1 in your last snippet, does that make any difference?

Comment: @Mahn Wow now it's fast, I got less than 10 ms, why localhost is slower?:O

Comment: Perhaps windows is mistakenly treating localhost as a IPv6, and eventually failing and falling back to an IPv4, or a firewall can't resolve localhost well.

Comment: Do you mind if I post the answer so you can mark it as accepted? :)

Comment: Yes, You can post it :) thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As discussed in the comments: changing localhost to 127.0.0.1 in the connection function often solves connection issues with PDO. [Here](http://drupal.org/node/1064342) is a thread that covers this topic on more detail.